# Read a file line by line and ignore some of them

Tags: windows, batch-file

I try to write a batch file that parses a file to create another one with its content.
But in the new one I will ignore every line which begin with the `-Dremote` pattern.

Here is my file

```
-nl
fr_yy
-clean
-vmargs
-Dgma.environnement=staging
-Duser.timezone=CET
-Dgma.communication=remote
-Dgma.security.disable=false
-Xms256M
-Xmx768M
-XX:PermSize=64m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-Dlogback.configurationFile=file:eclipse/conf-log/logback-error.xml
-Dshut.monitor.active=true
-Dshut.monitor.home=\\mynas05\GMData\Projets\RefonteUtilisateurs\Contrats\shut
-Dshut.applicationRuntimeEnv.systemPropertyKey=gma.environnement-nl
-Dremote_server_MessageWar=http://xxx.xxx.yy
-Dremote_port_MessageWar=40110
-Dremote_server_SinistreWar=http://xxx.xxx.yy
-Dremote_port_SinistreWar=40110
-Dremote_server_FacturationTiersWar=http://xxx.xxx.yy
```

And here is the code

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%tempFile%) do (
    set test=%%A
    IF NOT "!test:~0,7!"=="-Dremote"( type %%i>>%iniFile%)
)
```

But everything is copied in the iniFile...

Comment: if you want help, give us all of your code, not just a section, we dont know what %%i is defined as, or if you have delayed expansion enabled, etc... also, both provided answers do what you say you want, but neither does what you actually want, so please restate what you want, and give both example input and output files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in one line. Try this:

```
IF NOT "!test:~0,8!"=="-Dremote" (echo %%A>>%iniFile%)
```

1. You miscounted (`-Dremote` has 8 characters, not 7).
2. Use `echo` instead of `type`.
3. There is a space in the wrong position.
4. The wrong variable is used.

(I hope you are aware that you'll have to use delayed expansion (it's not in your code).)

Comment: Thanks! It works fine! The only thing I had to change is %tempFile% in the loop. I had to change it with the file name. With a variable it doesn't work...

Comment: I set it like that: Set tempFile="eclipse\tmp.ini"
Is something wrong?

Comment: yes, there is something wrong: with the doublequotes you tell `for` to treat it as a string instead of a filename. Use `set "tempFile=eclipye\tmp.ini"` (note the position of the `"`s)

Answer (score 2):

```
findstr /v /b /l /c:"-Dremote" "%tempFile%" >"%iniFile%"
```

(Test with a dummy `%iniFile%` first, of course...)

Comment: You should avoid writing entirely new code if possible, this is not a code writing service, and its best if we can modify the OP's code rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: @bryce yes, it does work with the data you provided.

Comment: +1 but you aren't explaining that this line is supposed to replace the OP's code *entirely*, which might be the reason why they were unable to make this solution work for them.

Answer (score 0):

A quick edit should fix it:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%tempFile%) do (
    set test=%%A
    IF NOT "!test:~0,7!"=="-Dremote"( echo !test!>>%iniFile%)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 7 to 8 "-Dremote" has 8 characters.
Add a SPACE after "-Dremote" before the round bracket.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%tempFile%) do (
set test=%%A
IF NOT "!test:~0,8!"=="-Dremote" ( echo !test!>>%iniFile%)
)
```